# How to sort by number in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a column stored as string, but it is really a number like this:

```
17 - Doe
2 - Mike
3 - James
```

I need to sort them and create a output like this:

```
2 - Mike
3 - James
17 - Doe
```

How to write the SQL? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

try this:

```
DECLARE @Yourtable table (data varchar(50))
insert into @Yourtable values ('17 - Doe')
insert into @Yourtable values ('2 - Mike')
insert into @Yourtable values ('3 - James')

SELECT * FROM @Yourtable order by CONVERT(int,left(data, charindex('-', data)-1))
```

**You shouldn't store your data this way, add a new int column to this table and run this to fix your table**:

```
DECLARE @Yourtable table (data varchar(50), newINT int)
insert into @Yourtable values ('17 - Doe',null)
insert into @Yourtable values ('2 - Mike',null)
insert into @Yourtable values ('3 - James',null)

UPDATE @Yourtable
    SET newINT=CONVERT(int,left(data, charindex('-', data)-1))
        ,data=RIGHT(data, LEN(data)-charindex('-', data)-1)
```

you can add an index to the new int column if you need to join or select by it.  Now you can do a regular ORDER BY on it.

Answer (score 2):

Two big assumptions - if the format is always as described then you can pull out the integer in your order by. Dont have sql server to test but something like this

```
order by cast(left(yourcol, charindex('-', yourcol) as integer))
```

Comment: will fail because '17 -' can't be converted to an int

Comment: If you change this to order by cast(left(yourcol, charindex('-', yourcol) - 2 as integer)), it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me If I've missed out a point, but I feel this is pretty simple and straightforward.
Below is the query i used to get your desired result. It will work for any number preceding a name..

`select col 
     from *table_name*
     order by convert(int,substring(id,0,charindex('-',id)));`

Kindly point out someone if I've missed something...